# Use AWS CLI to import existing resources into CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cli

I have a collection of CloudFormation templates that I'm using to create new resources but I also have a small percentage of AWS resources that were created outside of CF that I now want to import into CF. I know how to import existing resources into CF via the AWS dashboard but I want to do it with the CLI instead.

This is the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-new-stack.html) I thought would help but it appears to be out of date as I don't have a "--resources-to-import" option when I run `aws cloudformation create-stack help`. An up-to-date example would be very helpful if this is even possible via the command-line.

Comment: [Is This On Topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[In step 4 of the CLI documentation on that page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-new-stack.html#resource-import-new-stack-cli), it is actually a ***`create-change-set`*** call instead of a `create-stack` call:

[`aws cloudformation create-change-set --change-set-type IMPORT --resources-to-import`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-change-set.html)